# Issue - Two forms with the same CSS class name in casperjs

Tags: javascript

I have two forms in the same page with the  same CSS class names .

```
<form class="formFormatClass" >
</form>
<form class="formFormatClass" >
</form>
```

when I'm filling form data using the below code snippet , it is always considering the first form but not the second form.

```
this.fill('form.formFormatClass', {
      donorNumber :  DONOR_NUMBER_VALUE,
      firstName :    'srikanth',     
      lastName  :'',
      anyBloodGroup : 'true',
     dueToDonate : 'false' }, true);
```

How can I write code to fill in the second form without  making changes to the already designed JSP pages

Comment: Why don't you just use different classnames?

Comment: ...or give them `id`'s in addition, to differentiate them...

Comment: I don't know, if casperjs uses sizzle or the like. If it did, you could use `form.formFormatClass:nth-of-type(2)` as selector

Comment: I'm not allowed to modify the developers code

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested adding an id to each form will help distinguish them:

```
<form class="formFormatClass" id="form1">
</form>
<form class="formFormatClass" id="form2">
</form>

this.fill('#form1', {
      donorNumber :  DONOR_NUMBER_VALUE,
      firstName :    'srikanth',     
      lastName  :'',
      anyBloodGroup : 'true',
     dueToDonate : 'false' }, true);

this.fill('#form2', { ...
```

Comment: Thanks For your great Answers. I'm happy with it.

As I'm working in Automating the Test Environment, My idea is to work without modifying the developed code as it is been developed by some X developers.